# How can i write into csv file 2 different comments based on returned result using Python

Tags: python

I am trying to run Amazon Price checker and what i am trying to achieve is, if price < target_price send email(i will add this part later on)and write to the csv file Timpestamp & Date, Price and Comment  price has fallen and email was sent else if price > target_price don't send email just write to the csv file Timpestamp & Date, Comment  price too high email will not be  sent.

Here is my code

```
import csv

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime
import os
import time

# Requirement


# 1- Check Price


url = 'https://www.amazon.co.uk/Amazon-Fire-TV-Stick-4K-Ultra-Hd-With-Alexa-Voice-Remote-Streaming-Media-Player/dp/B079QB9BD7/ref=sr_1_2_mod_primary_new?dchild=1&keywords=amazon+fire+stick&qid=1608568582&sbo=RZvfv%2F%2FHxDF%2BO5021pAnSA%3D%3D&sr=8-2'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36'}


def check_stick_price():
    # this makes the request
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    # this extracts from page and  parses into html
    bs = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    # this gives us the product name by using 'productTitle' id - by adding .get_text() allows you to get display the text
    product_title = bs.find(id="productTitle").get_text()

    # this gets the price by using 'priceblock_dealprice' id
    price = bs.find(id="priceblock_ourprice").get_text()

    print(product_title.strip())

    return price


# Compare Price
price = check_stick_price()
target_price = str("£30")

# Create a file
file_exists = True

if not os.path.exists("../../MyProjects/Aamazon/price.csv"):
    file_exists = False

with open("../../MyProjects/Aamazon/price.csv", "a") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, lineterminator='\n')
    fields = ["Timestamp", "Price", "Comments"]
    if not file_exists:
        writer.writerow(fields)


    if  target_price > price:
        comment_email_Not_Sent = "too high email will not be sent"
        string = "Price is {}"  # place holder for above
        output = string.format(comment_email_Not_Sent)

    else:

        comment_email_Sent = "fallen and email was sent"
        string2 = " Price has {}"  # place holder for above
        output2 = string2.format(comment_email_Sent)

    timestamp = f"{datetime.datetime.date(datetime.datetime.now())} | {datetime.datetime.time(datetime.datetime.now())}"
    writer.writerow([timestamp, price, output,  output2])
    print("wrote data to file")
```

If i remove if condition in the comment sections it writes both comments into the file regardless of the result

[image]

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just do

```
   if  target_price > price:
        output = "Price is too high email will not be sent"
    else:
        output = "Price has fallen and email was sent"
```

and then

```
writer.writerow([timestamp, price, output])
```

Comment: Thanks, this works if target_price > price and sends writes one message to the file, but it doesn't write to the file target_price < price: - any suggestion?

Comment: This should work. Maybe you did mistake in code. Share your changed code.

Comment: Thanks it works, i had writer.writer.row in the wrong space i should have it like `if target_price > price:
        output = "Price is too high email will not be sent"
    else:
            output = "Price has fallen and email was sent"

    timestamp = f"{datetime.datetime.date(datetime.datetime.now())} | {datetime.datetime.time(datetime.datetime.now())}"
    writer.writerow([timestamp, price, output])
    print("wrote data to file")`